# Switching Frequency for flyback converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

What switching I should take for flyback voltage with input volt 230v and output volt as 12 v for 20 watts output power. Any small hint will be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, The faster the switching frequency, the lower the values of the external components (capacitors/inductors) needed, but you loose in efficiency (more heat produced). The choice is yours. EDIT: you need to provide more info in what you want to achieve, and more info in general. Why is switching frequency your concern?

Comment: There is no fixed answer. You need to balance that with size, cost and losses. Start your calculations with 100 kHz? What did you end up with. Test with 150 kHz. Better, worse?

Comment: If I answered: you must use 53.669 kHz, would you accept that as "the truth" or would you ask **why**?

Comment: Try "Power stage Designer" tool from TI.com ... v4.0 ...

Comment: Simply first : define you needs. Not for main 230 V.  https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/how-to-design-a-flyback-converter-in-seven-steps

Comment: What are your size and efficiency requirements? You want the frequency high enough so humans can't hear it. Lower frequency designs are easier. Higher frequency designs are physically smaller.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie..WHY?

Answer (score 2):

Many of the offline ac-dc power supplies you can find in consumer products operate at a fixed 65-kHz switching frequency. The reason is simple: the EMI standard for conducted emissions starts at 150 kHz and goes up to 30 MHz. When a flyback converter switches at 65 kHz, the second harmonic of the differential mode (DM) current is 130 kHz and is already attenuated compared to the fundamental value. Therefore, with a standard limit starting at 150 kHz (EN55032), you will consider the DM noise of the flyback converter at 195 kHz (3rd harmonic) which will already be attenuated compared to the fundamental, naturally easing the design of the filter.

[image]

Take the same converter and operate it at 100 kHz. The magnetics will surely be less bulky at this frequency but with a 200-kHz second harmonic less attenuated compared to the 3rd harmonic of the 65-kHz case, filtering can be more difficult. That being said, you can find many low-power switchers operating at 133 kHz, just before the standard starts, again eliminating the fundamental from the analysis.